# Boot Camp Low Audio Level Through 3.5mm Audio Jack

Tags: bootcamp, audio, windows

**Description:**

When using the 3.5mm audio output while booted into Windows 10, audio is barely audible at max volume; built-in speakers work perfectly. That is, the volume is very soft when my headphones are plugged in. Windows partition installed through Boot Camp Assistant.

**Device:** 2018 15" MacBook Pro, Vega 20 GPU.

**OS:** Tested on Windows 10 1809 AND 1903 (Both fully updated)

**Boot Camp Assistant Version:** 6.1.0 (6067.230.4)

**What I Have Tried:**

- Clean install Windows 10 1809 and 1903
- Enable and disable Windows Sonic For Headphones
- Cannot disable audio Enhancements (the tab is missing for some reason)
- Reinstall Mojave
- Reinstall Windows Support Software

**Observation:**

Cirrus audio driver does not seem to be installed, but rather Apple Audio Driver. I am assuming this is normal?

**Comments:**

Is this a driver issue or a "me" issue. Headphone audio level is normal while using macOS Mojave. Windows 10 installation went smoothly and was uneventful. I did not have this problem on my 2015 15" MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve tried reinstalling everything from the operating system to the audio driver. My current work around is to use a USB to audio output adapter.

Answer (score -1):

Apple audio is the correct driver as they ditched cirrus in this model.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: I have Apple audio is the correct driver as Apple now make their own audio chips in the latest Macs and no longer use cirrus as an audio component  hence Apple audio instead of cirrus. 

This answers one of the questions posed.